# Bootstrap resize text base on screen size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using `Bootstrap` in my `HTML` page and I have this row with text:

```css
.pick_your_color {
  font-size: 72px;
  font-family: piepie, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: rgb(75, 45, 30);
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="row text-center" style="padding-top: 280px">
  <h1 class="pick_your_color">Pick your color</h1>
</div>
```

Everything is working and loos ok, but when I resize the browser or using the mobile the text is using 2 lines instead of one line, There is a way to resize text to fit the row height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two two ways by which you can make text `responsive`:

- The text size can be set with a vw unit, which means the `viewport width`.

```css
.pick_your_color {
  font-size: 10vw;
  font-family: piepie, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: rgb(75, 45, 30);
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="row text-center" style="padding-top: 280px">
  <h1 class="pick_your_color">Pick your color</h1>
</div>
```

- or, You could also use `media queries` to change the font size of an element on specific screen sizes

```css
.pick_your_color {
  font-family: piepie, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: rgb(75, 45, 30);
  line-height: 1.2;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .pick_your_color {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
}


/* If the screen size is 600px wide or less, set the font-size of <div> to 30px */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .pick_your_color {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row text-center" style="padding-top: 280px">
  <h1 class="pick_your_color">Pick your color</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When `font-size` is set to `font-size: 72px;`, then it means that any viewport, display will have font size set to `72px`.

So it is possible to use `vw`.

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units)

> vw is 1% of the viewport's width.

Then you can write a class to define responsive text:

```
.foo-text {
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;    
    font-size: 3vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that based on the viewport width please look at this link: [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

Answer (score 0):

You can  use the following code.

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: calc(4vw + 4vh + 2vmin);
}
```

```html
<p>Dummy Text.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change font-size from `px` to `vh` then adjust value accordingly.
I've based this code on Enviro's suggestion.

```css
.pick_your_color {
    font-size: 6vh;
    font-family: piepie, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    color: rgb(75, 45, 30);
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="row text-center" style="padding-top: 280px">
        <h1 class="pick_your_color">Pick your color</h1>
</div>
```

Run code snippet and click full page, then try to resize your windows to see the expected result.